# Change the value of a submit button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I hava a button like this

```
<input type="Submit" value="Apply" align="MIDDLE">
```

I want to change the value to  something else .

Can I do this ?

```
<input type="Submit" value=<script>getnewkey("Apply")</script> align="MIDDLE">
```

It doesn't seem to work, How should I modify the javascript code?

Comment: Why the down-votes!? It's a clear a concise question. So it is an obvious error, so what? Answer it!

Comment: @Pilot In what way is this 'low quality'?

Comment: @oGeez asking this type of question simply means you dont even read A of javascript before posting it

Comment: I can call this as ummm basics, so though I've posted an answer, make sure you research about this online, you will get tons of posts who will provide you an answer for this, also learn basics of the language you are using to develop your apps/website with, if then you hit a bump, post a question here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhh it doesn't work that way, you should assign an `id` to the element and use

```
<input type="Submit" id="blow" value="Hello">
                   ------^------
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('blow').value = 'Apply';
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDtHU/)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code snippet. It will answer your questions

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language=javascript>
function onClickOfSubmit(){
    var renameTheTextBox = 'ChangedName';
    document.getElementById('textBoxId').value = renameTheTextBox;
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
    <input type="Submit" id="textBoxId" value="Submit" align="MIDDLE" onclick='onClickOfSubmit()'>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It seems the button value will change after I click it,am I right?

Comment: yes it will change after the click